# Pass data between prompts

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

Can i pass data between two prompts in yeoman?

Eg i've got two prompts like

```
{
  type: 'input',
  name: 'Name',
  message: 'Name?'
},{
  type: 'input',
  name: 'package',
  message: 'Package?',
  default: 'org.my.app.'+<prompt.name>
}
```

I want to show `name` property as default value for package? One way i can think of is:

- Show a template in default (like in example)
- Change the value later when creating the final template for user.

Another way that i tried is using `when`

```
{
  type: 'input',
  name: 'Name',
  message: 'Name?'
},{
  when: (response) => {
    this.testValue = response.Name
    return true
  },
  type: 'input',
  name: 'package',
  message: 'Package?',
  default: 'org.my.app.'+this.testValue
}
```

but it gives `undefined` even though inside the function value has been stored for in `this.testValue`

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally found the answer. The way to achieve it is using two prompt variables and running the second one after first's promise returns

```
const prompt1 = [{
  type: 'input',
  name: 'Name',
  message: 'Name?'
}];

return this.prompt(prompt1).then(props => {
  const prompt2 = [{
    type: 'input',
    name: 'package',
    message: 'Package?',
    default: 'org.my.app.'+props.name
  }];

  return this.prompt(prompt2).then(props => {
   //code goes here
  });
});
```